# LCM calculation

Tags: java, biginteger, greatest-common-divisor, lcm

I wrote code for the problem given in spoj to calculate LCM. I calculated the gcd of 2 numbers and I divided the multiplication of 2 numbers with gcd which gives the lcm of 2 numbers, but it is showing wrong answer.

The problem is at http://www.spoj.com/problems/WPC5I/

```
import java.math.BigInteger;
import java.util.Scanner;

class Lcm1 {
    public static void main(String args[]) throws Throwable {
        try {
            Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
            int siz = s.nextInt();
            for(int i = 0; i< siz; i++) {
                BigInteger a = s.nextBigInteger(), b = s.nextBigInteger();
                System.out.println((a.multiply(b)).divide(a.gcd(b)));
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e){}
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you using multiply() and divide() methods? It seems pointless compared to * and /. You should also post your gcd() method, there could be a problem there

Comment: This looks fine so far, can you give an example of a wrong result?

Comment: @Rishub we cannot use * and / for BigInteger

Comment: @Marco13 I too don't know that...while i'm submitting my code,it is showing that it is wrong

Comment: It seems that there has been **no** accepted Java solution for this problem until now. Just saying, who knows how they are testing it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your logic is partially wrong.Basically you are just calculating the lcm of given numbers but user asks to find least k satisfying given condition.but yours is not least k.
Try for case n=340 and m=230 actual ans is 1564 but your code gives 7820.

Note: lcm will not always be the least k satisfying given conditions in the problem.

Hint:prime factorize m,n and try to get the ans...try few more cases and you will get it.